# Constructor does weird things with optional parameters

Tags: python, constructor, optional-parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [least astonishment in python: the mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

I want to understand of the behavior and implications of the python `__init__` constructor.  It seems like when there is an optional parameter and you try and set an existing object to a new object the optional value of the existing object is preserved and copied.

Look at an example:

In the code below I am trying to make a tree structure with nodes and possibly many children .  In the first class `NodeBad`, the constructor has two parameters, the value and any possible children.  The second class `NodeGood` only takes the value of the node as a parameter.  Both have an `addchild` method to add a child to a node.

When creating a tree with the `NodeGood` class, it works as expected.  However, when doing the same thing with the `NodeBad` class, it seems as though a child can only be added once!

The code below will result in the following output:

```
Good Tree
1
2
3
[< 3 >]
Bad Tree
1
2
2
[< 2 >, < 3 >]
```

Que Pasa?

Here is the Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class NodeBad:
  def __init__(self, value, c=[]):
    self.value = value
    self.children = c
  def addchild(self, node):
    self.children.append(node)
  def __str__(self):
    return '< %s >' % self.value
  def __repr__(self):
    return '< %s >' % self.value


class NodeGood:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self.children = []
  def addchild(self, node):
    self.children.append(node)
  def __str__(self):
    return '< %s >' % self.value
  def __repr__(self):
    return '< %s >' % self.value

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print 'Good Tree'
  ng = NodeGood(1) # Root Node
  rootgood = ng
  ng.addchild(NodeGood(2)) # 1nd Child
  ng = ng.children[0]
  ng.addchild(NodeGood(3)) # 2nd Child

  print rootgood.value
  print rootgood.children[0].value
  print rootgood.children[0].children[0].value
  print rootgood.children[0].children

  print 'Bad Tree'
  nb = NodeBad(1) # Root Node
  rootbad = nb
  nb.addchild(NodeBad(2)) # 1st Child
  nb = nb.children[0]
  nb.addchild(NodeBad(3)) # 2nd Child

  print rootbad.value
  print rootbad.children[0].value
  print rootbad.children[0].children[0].value
  print rootbad.children[0].children
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is, the default value of an optional argument is only a single instance. So for example, if you say `def __init__(self, value, c=[]):`, that same list `[]` will be passed into the method each time an optional argument is used by calling code.

So basically you should only use immutable date types such as `None` for the default value of an optional argument. For example:

```
def __init__(self, value, c=None):
```

Then you could just create a new list in the method body:

```
if c == None:
  c = []
```

Comment: The problem only arises if you use **mutable** datatypes as default arguments. There is no problem with any **immutable** types (integer, string, tuple, etc.) (I would not name it *constant value*).

Comment: Good point, I just updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Worth clarifying that this isn't specific to `__init__`, or indeed to classes at all, but is true of any function.

Answer (score 3):

Mutable default arguments are a source of confusion.

See this answer: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)