# Python constructor argument not random bug?

Tags: python, random

I've just recently found this weird Python 'bug' and I wanted to see if anyone knew more about it!

for instance take the python module:

```
import random

class SaySomething:
    def __init__(self, value=random.randint(1, 3)):
        if value == 1: print 'one'
        elif value == 2: print 'two'
        elif value == 3: print 'three'

a = 0

while a < 10:
    SaySomething()
    a += 1
```

This code will for some reason print the SAME number 10 times!!! Now this I DO NOT understand. It seems that the constructor is being called with the same values 10 consecutive times. But if you print each `SaySomething()` you'll see that they all have different pointer addresses, so they aren't the same object.

Now if you change:

```
SaySomething()
```

to

```
SaySomething(random.randint(1, 3))
```

It runs as expected, with actual random choices being made.

Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: The [default argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) issue strikes again!

Comment: Wow, sucha fast and useful bunch of responses here! I wish I could say you all answered my question! Thanks to everyone who helped out, makes a LOT of sense now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python constructor does weird things with optional parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899643/python-constructor-does-weird-things-with-optional-parameters)

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that the default arguments in Python are evaluated once, when the function is created. To fix this, try:

```
    def __init__(self, value = None):
        if value is None:
             value = random.randint(1, 3)

        if value == 1: print 'one'
        elif value == 2: print 'two'
        elif value == 3: print 'three'
```

This way, we shift the randomization into the function itself, instead of at the time of function definition.

Answer (score 4):

In python, default arguments are initialized once. So you are getting the same value over and over, because that was the value when the default argument was initialized. See http://www.deadlybloodyserious.com/2008/05/default-argument-blunders/

Answer (score 3):

It's because when the class is compiled or interpreted the value of variable `value` is set to `random.randint(1, 3)`, and it doesn't changes until you pass some other value to it.

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason as in [Python constructor does weird things with optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899643/python-constructor-does-weird-things-with-optional-parameters)

the default value of an optional argument is a single instance and thus is only calculated once for all instances being made.

To fix this:

```
import random 
class saySomething: 
    def __init__(self, value = None):
        random_value = random.randint(1, 3) if value == None else value
        if random_value in [1, 2, 3] print ['one', 'two', 'three'][random_value - 1]

for a in xrange(10):
    saySomething()
```

Comment: You could also do a closure, as in `def __init__(self, value=lambda: random.randint(1, 3)):`, but it doesn't make much sense for this situation ;)